# Install Cumulative Update file(.msu) using USB Drive

Tags: windows-10, usb-drive

Is it possible to install Windows 10 Cumulative Update using bootable USB Drive. My PC now had an issue of displaying black screen with mouse cursor on restarting. I tried all solutions given through online communities. Nothing worked for me. May be installing new update will be a solution for this problem and which can be possible only through USB boot. My PC has Windows 10 version 1709.

Comment: It depends on the USB format type..

Comment: this question belongs to superuser.com. Use [Dism /Image:C:\ /LogPath:AddPackage.log /Add-Package /PackagePath:E:\KB123456.msu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-operating-system-package-servicing-command-line-options) to install the update to an not running windows